# Using number pad for keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, system-settings

I'm on ubuntu 20.04. I can't use the 4, 8, 6 and 2 keys for shortcuts on my numberpad. I'm using the keyboards shortcuts section in settings. Using something like 7 for shortcut actually performs the 'home' function before actually finishing the shortcut.

Can you please tell me why this is? And how I can use them for keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: so have you pressed the numlock key and tried that?

Answer (score 1):

if you have numlock turned off, button "7" is actually "home" button. Only when numlock is on, it would write "7" and work with other combination of keys as shortcut. You can force numlock to be always on with `gnome-tweaks`. Where you can configure it under `Typing-->Miscellaneous Compatibility Options, set "Numeric keypad keys always enter digits"`. That will force keyboard to always enter digits, so shortcuts like `CTRL + 7` would actually perform what you need, and it will not read as `CTRL + Home`

Comment: This comment, which is not an answer does not answer what was asked.

Comment: David, are you sure? Because they wrote that when he press 7, it will do "home", which my answer solve. And if they have shortcut binded to ctrl + 7 (not ctrl + home) then by pressing ctrl + 7 when numlock is on, will trigger shortcut.

Comment: My opinion is that this is the right answer. Numlock must be on for keypad numbers to be recognized as such by the system.